# Android Button setBackgroundResource() method does not persist changed background

Tags: android, android-button

I am using following code to change the background with new images when clicked. When I click on the button, the background changes for few seconds, then it reverts to the original background. I don't know why this happening.

```
final Button btn_tab3 = new Button(this);
btn_tab3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.reservation);
btn_tab3.setLayoutParams(par);
btn_tab1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btn_tab1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.delivery_tab_selector);
        btn_tab2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pickup);
        btn_tab3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.reservation);
        mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: So the background will change back as soon as you release your finger? or does it have a delay? Are there any other actions you perform within the time that it changes back?

Comment: No I am not performing any other action rather than this code